# Android Network Transferring Objects

Tags: android, sockets, networking, pojo

For my Android project I need to transfer some simple (POJO) Java objects between two mobile phones. The aim is to connect them together via WiFi (Tethering) and to transfer some basic objects like:

```
int id;
String name;
float positionX;
...
```

From my Java experiences I was thinking about using a simple socket connection but since I'm using Android I thought there might be a better way of doing it.
Has anyone experiences with this? What would you suggest?

Comment: Bluetooth might be better than trying to connect them via WiFi. It also depends on how often you need to do it, if you need confirmation that it arrived, and how easy you want it to be for you to code.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this. So first: I need a connection to more than one client. I guess it will be three or four devices. Secondly I need it pretty fast since I want to make a game.
Thats why I tought about a Socket Connection but who knows.
Besides, it will be one Server and several clients so a p2p network seems the wrong idea to me. Or isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the data is very complex, I'd convert the objects to JSON when sending them to the server, and then back to POJO's when reading them on the client.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.
So should I send these JSON objects via a simple socket connection or is there anything else better? I never established a network connection on Android so it would help me to know what would be the best way (e.g. using special Classes, Handler, Helper etc.)

Comment: I'd go for an HTTP server and use the HTTP protocol for sending data between the server and the clients.

Comment: Ah, thank you for your answer. So is a HTTP Server really faster than a "simple" socket connection?

Comment: No, it's not faster, but I think development will be faster. Especially when more features are added to your game protocol. I'm not saying HTTP is the only/best way to go, but it deals with much of the stuff you would otherwise have to implement. On the client side, see e.g. http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html